# Make variable persist outside of if block in C#

Tags: c#, razor, scope

Can I have a variable persist from an if code block?

I have

```
if(some condition){
  var result=queryexecute(some query);
}

...Some non dependent code...

if(result != null){
  ....
}
```

Im getting a result doesnt exist in current context. Im guessing result is local to that if block. Due to code between the two, I dont want ot combine the two code block. Any way to have result defined at the second if block?

The return type for queryexecute is 'public static IEnumerable'. I am far too knew at this to know how to declare an empty object of that type. But I can do that to if anybody would be so nice as to elucidate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to switch from `var` to a declared type:

```
IEnumerable result = null; //or whatever it is

if(some condition){
  result=queryexecute(some query);
}

...Some non dependent code...

if(result != null){
  ....
}
```

Comment: ok that makes sense. I posted an edit above, could you tell me what type i use to declare it given that return type.

Comment: If `IEnumerable` is the return of the method then `IEnumerable` is the variable type.

Comment: I updated the example.  Now if it's a generic type of IEnumerable<SomeOtherType> then the variable will need to be declared like that as well.

Comment: In Visual studio, mouse of `var` when you have `var result=queryexecute(some query);` and that's another way to tell what type it is infering.

Comment: Thankyou sir. One last question do you know what type WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord would be? I unfortunately dont have any way of viewing the variable types.

Comment: I haven't really messed with web matrix, but looking at msdn, DynamicRecord is a class under WebMatrix.Data, so a variable would be `WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord someVariableName;`

Comment: lol yes it is. I finally just went ahead and tried using that full thing as the type. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
var result = some_condition ? queryexecute(somequery) : null;

// ...

if (result != null) {
    ...
}
```